# Correct way to look for a item property in python list with least time and code complexity

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of suppliers eg.

`suppliers=[]` in which i have a n number of elements in somewhat following way eg `[{"supplierId":"1","aCode":2},{"supplierId":"1","aCode":3}]`

Now, I need to check based on the value of a property, lets say `areaCode=2` and need to check if area code  is in list of suppliers  named as `aCode`. 
How can I detemine the area Code exists with minimum time and code complexity and by not using for loops as I will have a lot of data in suppliers array.

Comment: Do you just want to see if it exists? or print the result if it does exist? A for loop is going to be the fastest. You can one line it by leaving the looping to a different function but it isn't as fast as a regular loop.

Comment: searching through a data structure which holds multiples values cannot be done without a loop/recursion as per my limited knowledge, it's a programming construct and not generally a bad thing. In order to improve performance, you can use `pandas`

Comment: `in` runs a loop under the hood in the Python implementation, generally much faster than a plain `for` loop (but PyPy has fast loops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case because it is a list of `dict` it is hard to not use a loop.  If you only want to see if it exists you can one line it such as:

```
print(any(areaCode==x['aCode'] for x in suppliers))
```

or if you want the entries you can one line it like this:

```
suppliers_in_area = [x for x in suppliers if x['aCode'] == areaCode]
```

Both versions require a `for` loop and both are equally fast but the first one requires minimal memory.

**- Edit -**

If you just one the first occurrence (or if only one element exists) then short circuit your `for` loop.

```
def get_supplier_by_area(area_code):
    for supplier in suppliers:
        if supplier['aCode'] == area_code:
            return supplier
    # It will return None if nothing is found
```

or you can use a generator if you want to return the `next` supplier every time to call the function.

```
def get_supplier_by_area(area_code):
    for supplier in suppliers:
        if supplier['aCode'] == area_code:
            yield supplier
try:
    gen = get_supplier_by_area('A01')
    print(next(gen)) # will print the first result or will raise a StopIteration error
    print(next(gen)) # will print the second result or will raise a StopIteration
except StopIteration:
    print("No more results")
```

Comment: Thanks.This would help for start .will update on as there are multiple conditions i have join and check from various lists and based on that i need to create a response

Comment: You may want to consider turning it into a `dict` of `dicts`. Then you can do faster loop ups down the road.

Comment: if i want only one item  out of it the how can i modify the code you shared above .lets say i want to avoid using index like 0

Comment: @divyanayanawasthi can you provide a better example? Like you want to return the first result? Or you want to return all results but the index 0 one? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: what i meat was i would always have one item in the list which would be valid  so instead of using array[0] to get that element i  wanted a better strucutre.as of now i used  like this -->  valid_supplier =next((supplier for supplier in suppliers if best_buy['xxxx'] == supplier.xxxx\
                      and best_buy['yyyy'] == supplier.yyyy), None)

Comment: Looks Good..especially with yield ..in case  there can be  items to be retrieved more than one.Excepting this as answer ..thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The inner items are dictionaries, they can be referenced by their key.

```
def main():
    list1=[{"supplierId":"1","aCode":2},{"supplierId":"1","aCode":3}]
    searchKey=2
    for item in list1:
        if item['aCode']==searchKey:
            print(item)

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```